# MySQL Select Query: Calculate Counts and Get Totals

Tags: mysql

I need to combine all the Start_Stop_ID and End_Stop_ID into one ID column, but I need to count the number of Start and End for each Stop_ID into separate columns.

Every row of Start_Stop_ID has Current_Fare. I need to calculate the total of the Current_Fare associated with the Start_Stop_ID, not End_Stop_ID.

```
The columns would be:
ID | Start | END | TOTAL

Example:
There would be rows such as
E1      | 1 | 0 | 3.50
BUSDOME | 3 | 0 | 18.50 (BUSDOME has 3 Start_Stop_ID, 10.50, 4.00 and 4.00)
N4      | 1 | 3 | 1.50
E5      | 2 | 0 | 6.00  (E5 has 2 Start_Stop_ID, 3.00 and 3.00)
E7      | 0 | 1 | 0.00
```

Trip Table

[image: Trip Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
SELECT i.ID, SUM(i.Start) Start, SUM(i.End) End, SUM(i.Total) Total FROM (
    SELECT Start_Stop_ID ID, COUNT(Start_Stop_ID) AS Start, 0 AS End, SUM(Current_Fare) AS Total 
    FROM trip_table GROUP BY ID
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT End_Stop_ID ID, 0 AS Start, COUNT(End_Stop_ID) AS End, 0 AS Total 
    FROM trip_table WHERE End_Stop_ID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ID
    ORDER BY ID ASC) i 
GROUP BY i.ID
```

What this query does is to create a result based on the Start_Stop_ID, and another result set based on End_Stop_ID, then uses UNION ALL to combine them together before summing the totals.

When creating the first result set, End will be 0 as we are only counting the starting stop IDs. When creating the second result set, Start will be 0, and Total (fare) is also 0 because fare is only associated with the start result set.

*Fixed a typo in query

Answer (score 1):

This will calculate the fare total and perform a count, but the logic of the other column `|End|` isn't clear.

```
select Start_Stop_ID, count(*) num_stops, sum(Current_Fare) AS total
from trip_tableclear
group by Start_Stop_ID
```

Comment: I guess the first column is the count of each ID in Start_Stop_ID and the second the count of each ID in End_Stop_ID. Thus, N4 is present once in Start_Stop_ID and 3 times in End_Stop_ID. Then, : N4 | 1 | 3 | 1.50
It seems the sum is based only on Current_Fare for IDs which are present in the first column.

Comment: I want to calculate the total count of End_Stop_ID and put it into a column, but it would be in the same row as the count of Start_Stop_ID.

Comment: As @Arcesilas said, The sum of Current_Fare is only based on Start_Stop_ID

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Query :**

```
SELECT Start_Stop_ID as 'ID', count(num_stops) as 'Count', SUM(Current_Fare) as 'Total Fare' FROM trip_tableclear GROUP BY Start_Stop_ID;
```